# Linear space and subspaces, conclusions

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear space $X$ on $\mathbb{C}$ there are given two **subsets**: $U, V$ such that $U,V\subset X$.  We also know that $U\cap V$ is linear subspace of $X$.  Then:
**a.** Both $U$ and $V$ contain zero vector
**b.** one of the subsets $U,V$ is linear subspace of $X$
**c.** subset $\{u+v\in X: u\in U, v\in V\}$ is linear subspace of $X$.
**My approach**
**a.** It is true, because $U\cap V$ is linear subspace. We know that each linear subspace contain zero vector.
**c.** is false, for example $X=\mathbb{R}^2,U=\{0\}$ and $V=\{[2,2]\}$ Then $\{u+v\in X: u\in U, v\in V\}$ is not linear subspace.
**b.**  It is false, $X=\mathbb{R}^2, U=\{[0,0], [1,2]\}V=\{[0,0],[2,1]\}$. Then $U\cap V$ is linear subspace but neither $U$ nor $V$ is linear subspace.
Tell me please, if my answers are correct (first of all I mean my explanations).

Comment: One of your explanations is incorrect.

Comment: in c) you forgot to include the $0$ vector in your $V$ - right?

Comment: @peterag, right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd explain **a** a bit more. Something like

> Since $U\cap V$ is a subspace, $0\in U\cap V$. Therefore, $0$ belongs to both $U$ and $V$.

And the example of **c** is incorrect because $U\cap V=\emptyset$, which is not a subspace.